# Sum of all items in a for loop kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a for loop like this:

```
 for( datax in it.data.data){                 
     listSum = datax.total
  }
```

This for loop returns items like this

```
100
200
300
```

as it should.

Now, I simply want to sum all the items, then get a total of **600**

I tried:

```
val nums = listOf(listSum!!.toInt())
val sum = nums.sum()
```

But this returns the last item - **300**

**Data Class**

```
..........
val `data`: List<DataXX>

...................
data class DataXX(
val __v: Int,
val _id: String,
val total: String)
```

How can I sum all items in a for loop with kotlin?

Comment: in your for loop, are you adding the values to a list? because in your code it doesn't look like you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use [sumBy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum-by.html) function:

```
it.data.data.sumBy { datax -> datax.total.toInt() }
```

Comment: Still didnt work. Tested with 3 numbers - 30,0000, 60,000 and 120,000. 
It returned 360,000 as the sum

Comment: @Ibramazin Could you add the code for your data structures to the question?

Comment: I have added it, please check

Comment: @Ibramazin I've updated the answer. Am I right that you need to sum the values in the `total` field?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ambiguous but I guess this in what you want:

```
var listSum = 0

for( datax in it.data.data){                 
     listSum += adatax.total.toInt()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in the for loop:

```
 for( datax in it.data.data){                 
     listSum += datax.total
  }
```

Comment: This is not working. It returns null and a weird number null20000620000023